# Create new table with a sum where row from table 2 matches field in table 1 and aggregate on another field

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

I am fairly new to SQL so apologies if my terminology is incorrect. I am looking to summarise a number of measurable's from "Table 2" but in the example below I have only included 1 for ease. I would like to insert the results into a a new table (Table 3).

I use pgAdmin 4.

## Tables and contents

### Table 1

This has two useful fields. Field 1 is named "Code_1" but this is not a unique field. Field 2 is named "Code_2" and this is unique. This table basically highlights all the features in "Code_2" and shows which features they are linked to in "Code_1".

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1 (Code_1 int, Code_2 int)

INSERT INTO Table_1 (Code_1, Code_2) VALUES  (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6)
```

> ```
> code_1 | code_2
> -----: | -----:
>      1 |      1
>      1 |      2
>      1 |      3
>      2 |      4
>      2 |      5
>      2 |      6
> ```

### Table 2

The features in "Code_2" also have a number of measurable's associated with them but as explained above there is only one in this example - "Measure_1".

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2 (Code_2 int, Measure_2 int)

INSERT INTO Table_2 (Code_2, Measure_2) VALUES (1,50), (2,75), (3,100), (4,25), (5,25), (6,50)
```

> ```
> code_2 | measure_2
> -----: | --------:
>      1 |        50
>      2 |        75
>      3 |       100
>      4 |        25
>      5 |        25
>      6 |        50
> ```

### Output table

I would like to create a new table (Table 3) with "Code_1" (unique) which is a sum of all the measures ("Measure_1") associated with "Code_2" which is associated with "Code_1).

> ```
> code_1 | sum_measure_1
> -----: | ------------:
>      1 |           225
>      2 |           100
> ```

Comment: Please try not to use images when possible. Instead add the `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO....` statements to your question to allow for easy reproduction of the issue/question. I've edited your question to show you how this can be achieved. It allows for better understanding and can provide a way to produce a working environment for e.g. db<>fiddle as I added in Akina's answer. Welcome to DBA.SE.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use - thanks for the edit and guidance.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t1.code_1, SUM(t2.measure_1)
FROM table1 t1
NATURAL JOIN table2 t2
GROUP BY t1.code_1
```

A working example can be found at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=eb570a7f63b5e2684818a4a6069b2427) where I used the PostgreSQL 10 engine. You can build on this example.

Instead of using a static table, you might want to consider using a view instead. This has the advantage that the values will be calculated on-the-fly and aren't static.

Comment: Thank you - so if I wanted to sum a "Measure_2" would I put SUM(t2.measure_1), SUM(t2.measure_2)?

Comment: @AWGIS I think you may simply test and look at the result correctness... :)

Comment: I slightly edited your answer to provide a working example on db<>fiddle and a hint about views. I hope you don't object, as I was trying to create a working example of a good, high quality and lasting Q & A. Please feel free to [rollback](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/258250/revisions) your answer if you feel I have abused your answer to a degree that does not meet your initial intention.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use I very rarely object to editing and adding to my answers. I sometimes find it difficult to give explanations - English is not my native language. Thank you.